# Hosting both faceook app and website on same server with apahe and tomcat

Tags: facebook, apache, tomcat, ssl, virtualhost

I have a facebook application hosting on a server using tomcat. I have also apache server on the same machine where I handle incoming requests and redirect them based on if it is coming secure port(SLL 443)  or 80 (standard HTTP port). I have only one domain which is www.myfacebookapp.net.

The problem starts when I need to host my app and website on the same server.  Normally it shouldn't be a problem however both my app and website have to support SSL (Facebook made it mandatory as it does not accept any connection which is not secure (not https) )

Below is the summary of my configuration

1. I have only one domain which is www.yarimelma.net
2. I have SSL certificate which supports only one domain.
3. I have served my static web page content under /var/www/http/public_html/index.html
4. My tomcat instance runs on 8080 and my application path is www.myfacebookapp.net/myApp
5. So when I run my facebook app, it makes a POST request to URL: https://www.myfacebookapp.net/myApp
6. I have configured my apache instance with virtual hosts such that,

   ```
    VirtualHost1 (*: 80) 
         ServerName www.myfacebookapp.net
         DocumentRoot /var/www/http/public_html/
    VirtualHost1 (*: 443)  #direct to tomcat
         ServerName www.myfacebookapp.net
         DocumentRoot /var/www/http/public_html/ ProxyPreserveHost On
         ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/ 
         ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
         ServerName www.myfacebookapp.net
         SSLEngine on
         #other ssl related config
   ```

It works fine with my facebook app and also webpage when I access my webpage from 80 (http://www.myfacebookapp.net) However, I should also support my webpage support https connections. Unfortunately, I can not achieve this with this configuration. So what I would like to do,

- Access web page by https such that https://www.myfacebookapp.net
- Also, keep tomcat redirection from the secure port when it is being accessed by URL https://www.myfacebookapp.net/myApp (which facebooks invoke to render facebook app iframe)

Is it possible to achieve this without any additional domain name and SSL certificate?

I couldn't find any configuration such that,

1. if the request comes from https://www.myfacebookapp.net/myApp *:443 -> then redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8080 (tomcat to server app)
2. If the request comes from https://www.myfacebookapp.net -> then redirect to /var/www/html/public_html (to serve webpage)

Apache documentation says that I cant define two virtual hosts for both 443 (https) and same domain.

Basically, I want to host my facebook app and website on the same server and both should be accessible through https.

Anyone knows any solution about this?

Thanks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is only one VirtualHost on port 443, and do conditionnal redirection inside it for the Tomcat part.  Like so:

```
Listen *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog "logs/443-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/443-access_log" combined

    DocumentRoot /var/www/http/public_html

    SSLEngine On
    # OTHER SSL RELATED CONFIGURATIONS

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/

</VirtualHost>
```

Some details:

- The ServerAlias is only valid if your domain without www exists, remove it otherwise.
- I like to have separated logs for each VirtualHost.  It gives you more control on the LogLevel, and is easier to debug if you have many.
- Since ProxyPass is setup for `/myapp`, all other requests will be served from the static files in your DocumentRoot directory.

FYI, the reason you cannot run 2 VirtualHosts with SSL on the same domain is because certificate negotiation between the browser and Apache is done *before* Apache knows which domain the browser is requeting.  When it sees a request on port 443, it takes the firts VirtualHost if finds and uses that certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is an excellent solution. However, when I haev configured as you suggested shown below,

ProxyPass       /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/

It directs me to the default tomcat page (root) instead of /myapp. I am not sure how it was working before when it was defined;

ProxyPass        /     http://127.0.0.1:8080/ 

any suggestion on this?
many thanks

Comment: You can to `ProxyPass /myapp/ 127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/`.